# angularjs dynamic sort of JSON data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to show below data in ascending order in select box.

Data is as under :-

```
 [
  {
"value": "MKZ_2017_LCN2014",
"text": "林肯MKZ"
},
{
"value": "MKX_2016_LCN2014",
"text": "林肯MKX"
},
{
 "value": "MKC_presidential_LCN2014",
"text": "林肯总统系列MKC(Oasis)"
},
{
"value": "MKZ_2015_360used_LCN2014",
"text": "林肯MKZ(360)"
}
]
```

View code is :-

```
<select
  class="select-modal"
  ng-model="key3" 
  id="model-03-1"
  name="third-primary-model" 
  ng-options="nameplate.text for nameplate in thirdLevelDropDown track by nameplate.value"
  ng-change="getCarModel3(key3)"
   >
    <option value="">Select</option>
   </select>
```

I want to sort select box on the name of text.

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, Use `| orderBy:'text'`

```
  <select class="select-modal" ng-model="key3" id="model-03-1" name="third-primary-model" ng-options="nameplate.text for nameplate in thirdLevelDropDown | orderBy:'text'" ng-change="getCarModel3(key3)">
      <option value="">Select</option>
    </select>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/tgLcfjxd/)**

Comment: @AniruddhaDas which one?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
ng-options="nameplate.text for nameplate in (models | orderBy: 'text') track by nameplate.value"
```